# How Do I Call HttpClient in Service for a Blazor Client-Side App

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

I want to make Http calls from a service in Blazor rather than making calls in the `@code` block in the `.razor` file nor in a code-behind. I receive the error:
`Shared/WeatherService.cs(16,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

The documentation shows that this *is* how it's done.

> Complex services might require additional services. In the prior
>   example, DataAccess might require the HttpClient default service.
>   @inject (or the InjectAttribute) isn't available for use in services.
>   Constructor injection must be used instead. Required services are
>   added by adding parameters to the service's constructor. When DI
>   creates the service, it recognizes the services it requires in the
>   constructor and provides them accordingly.

*Source: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#use-di-in-services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#use-di-in-services_)*

How do I remedy the error?

```cs
// WeatherService.cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyBlazorApp.Shared
{
    public interface IWeatherService
    {
        Task<Weather> Get(decimal latitude, decimal longitude);
    }

    public class WeatherService : IWeatherService
    {
        public WeatherService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            ...
        }

        public async Task<Weather> Get(decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }

    }
}
```

```cs
// Starup.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MyBlazorApp.Shared;

namespace MyBlazorApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IWeatherService, WeatherService>();
        }

        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing `using System.Net.Http;` to have access to the class in `WeatherService.cs`

Comment: Be clear about Client-side or Server-side Blazor, for HttpClient there are some subtle differences.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Can you elaborate what you're asking? "Client-Side" is in the title of my question for that reason specifically if I understand what you mean. Did I miss something?

Comment: No, I just missed that in the title. Was looking at text & tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `using System.Net.Http;` to have access to the class in `WeatherService.cs`

```
// WeatherService.cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http; //<-- THIS WAS MISSING

namespace MyBlazorApp.Shared {
    public interface IWeatherService {
        Task<Weather> Get(decimal latitude, decimal longitude);
    }

    public class WeatherService : IWeatherService {
        private HttpClient httpClient;

        public WeatherService(HttpClient httpClient) {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<Weather> Get(decimal latitude, decimal longitude) {
            // Do stuff
        }

    }
}
```

If using the full name for the class `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` does not work then you are definitely missing a reference to the assembly.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change the error. Also, the docs should state that if it is indeed the case.

Comment: @dapperdan1985 The docs are not perfect. You could check here for information about HttpClient  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: They also make reference to the namespace here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it still won't build with the `using`. Same error. Is it building for you?

Comment: @dapperdan1985 check to make sure that the assembly is referenced

Comment: @dapperdan1985 if using the full name for the class `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` does not work then you are definitely missing a reference to the assembly.

Comment: okay. I'll have to try this in Visual Studio. I'm trying to do it in VS Code. My csproj has a `<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />`, but still not doing the trick.

Comment: Adding `using System.Net.Http;` is all that was required. When that doesn't work the project was damaged in some other way. That `<PackageReference ` shoul dnot be needed and is not a good idea.

Comment: Visual Studio showed that other errors were present, but building with `dotnet build` only showed the `...HttpClient could not be found...` error. Using Visual Studio (as opposed to VS Code) picked up the real error much more effectively. I suppose I should be less stubborn and develop on Windows instead of Ubuntu so I can have full Visual Studio :)

Comment: @dapperdan1985 glad you found a solution. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure httpclient in startup.cs.

```
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
```

Now you can use HttClient in .razor files.

```
@inject HttpClient httpClient

-------------

private async Task LoadSystems() => systemsList = await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<List<Models.Systems>>("Systems/GetSystems");
```